# WFS GetFeature: Is DWithin selection equal to an Intersect selection using a circle?

Tags: wfs, getfeature

I can't find any WFS implementations that support circle geometries for selection. There is the DWithin spatial selection but I can't find the specification of what is actually does.

1. Does it select objects where the geometry is entirely within the specified distance? 
   Or
2. Does it select objects where some part of the geometry is within the specified distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`There is the DWithin spatial selection but I can't find the specification of what is actually does.`

The specification you are looking for is the OGC Filter Encoding (FE) Specification, see the [OGC Filter Encoding page for a list](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/filter) of the specifications (current and deprecated).

I note in the latest version that came out after this question was raised that there is a clarification for DWithin, soperhaps you weren't the only one scratching their head.:

> vii. OGC Change Requests processed in this corrigendum
>
> [OGC 11-057] FES OGC Filter Encoding 2.0 Corrigendum - DWithin Clarification

This document tells us:

> 7.8.3.3 DWithin and Beyond operators
>
> The spatial operators DWithin and Beyond shall test whether the value of a geometric property A is within or beyond a specified distance d of the specified literal geometric value B. More specifically:
>
> ```
>    DWithin(A,B,d) = Distance(A,B) < d
>    Beyond(A,B,d) = Distance(A,B) > d[10]
> ```
>
> Distance values shall be expressed using the fes:Distance element. The content of the fes:Distance element shall represent the magnitude of the distance and the uom attribute shall be used to specify the units of measure. Units of measure can be expressed as symbols or as a URI that links to a definition of a unit of measure that may not have a conventional symbol or when it is desired to indicate a precise or variant definition.
>
> EXAMPLE         The following XML fragment:
>
> 10
>
> encodes a distance value of 10 m.
>
> If there is only one argument (i.e. one child element specified for the operator, the calling service shall apply the operator to the geometric values of all the spatial properties of the resource[11]. In this case, the operator shall evaluate to true if all tested spatial property values fulfill the spatial relationship implied by the operator. Otherwise, the operator shall evaluate the specified arguments (i.e. the two child elements) and test whether their geometric values satisfy the implied spatial relationship.

Comment: Thanks, better late then never I guess. Had already forgotten I ever asked this question.